# How to get inline styles for a specific css file in the head tag while extractCss is in true?

Tags: webpack, nuxt.js

When I reload the page, i get html without styles, because the styles are loaded later. I need to put the critical css into tag style in the head tag, but extractCss put all my styles in the link tag.

some code from my nuxt.config.js

```js
export default {
  build: {
    cssSourceMap: false,
    extractCSS: true,

    extend(config, ctx, isServer) {
      if (ctx.isClient) {
        ctx.loaders.vue.transformAssetUrls.img = ['data-src', 'src']
        ctx.loaders.vue.transformAssetUrls.source = ['data-srcset', 'srcset']
        config.devtool = isDevelopment ? '#source-map' : ''
        config.module.rules.push({
          enforce: 'pre',
          test: /\.(js|vue)$/,
          loader: 'eslint-loader',
          exclude: /(node_modules)/,
          options: {
            fix: true,
           },
         })
      }
    }
  }
}
```

[tag head](https://prnt.sc/15ssi5h)

Comment: Wait, how do you load your CSS later? Never seen a behavior like this. Aren't you writing your css in the `style` tag? This is somewhat already done for you out of the box.

Comment: When a browser loads some site, html downloading first, then styles (source: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Performance/How_browsers_work). Even with a rel preload, styles are not loaded immediately.

Comment: Of course, maybe I'm wrong about the comment above)

Comment: Do you have some code? This should be working totally fine from a freshly crated Nuxt project.

Comment: https://prnt.sc/15ssmdy my nuxt.config;

https://prnt.sc/15ssi5h - tag head.

I want the styles of one specific file to be connected not via a link, but in the style tag

Comment: So, why are you even doing all of this? What's your initial goal?